# python file read with different size of lines

Tags: python, file

I try to read file such as

```
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7\n 
2 3 4 5 2 3 4 7 8 2 3\n 
3 1 2 4 2 1 4 5 6 2
```

something like that, and I want to rewrite the file such as

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
...
3 2
```

However, I have no idea how to store different size of lines. The basic code is below, but dst[] part must be changed.

```
while 1:
        line = file1.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    src, tmp, dst[] = line.split(' ') 
    # rewrite part will be here
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After `1 4` is it `1 5` `1 6` `1 6` `1 7` ?

Comment: What is the `tmp` used for. It looks like you're printing out `src, tmp` and then printing out `src, x` for each `x` in `dst`. If so, that's equivalent to just splitting into `src` and `dst` and printing our `src, x` for each `x` in `dst` without the special `tmp` case (which is what everyone else's answer assumes). Is there anything we're all missing here that makes `tmp` useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `itertools.product` (only because I when writing I was unsure whether there was meant to be one or two parameters):

```
from itertools import product

with open('testing2.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        items = line.split()
        first, rest = items[0], items[1:]
        for i, j in product(first, rest):
            print i, j
```

Comment: Using `itertools.product` is a very nice solution to the part the OP apparently claims to already know how to write. It doesn't solve the line he doesn't know how to write, which is handled in your line `first, rest = items[0], items[1:]`. And that's not equivalent to what he's attempting to do, because he seems to need `items[1]` separate from `items[2:]`, even though I'm not sure why he needs it.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
In [1]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         spl=line.split()
   ...:         first,rest=spl[0],spl[1:]
   ...:         for x in rest:
   ...:             print first,x  # instead of printing write 
                                   # it to a file using 
                                   # write("{0} {1}\n".format(first,x)
   ...:             
   ...:             
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
...
...
3 6
3 2
```

Comment: As with @JonClements, you're not getting the OP the separate `tmp` and `dst` variables, or `spl[1]` and `spl[2:]` in your rewrite. It may be that he doesn't actually need them separate, but he seems to think that he does, and that he can write the rest of the code once he has them.

Comment: @abarnert if that's the case then how come he has `3 2` as the last pair in the expected output?

Comment: If what's the case? As I said, "It may be that he doesn't actually need them separate, but he seems to think that he does." Until he answers my comment above, we really don't know _why_ he thinks he needs it. If you want to guess why he thinks he needs it and explain why he's wrong, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

The line you want to write is this:

```
src, tmp, dst[] = line.split(' ')
```

There's no direct way to do this. You're looking for what's called pattern-match assignment, which a few languages (like Haskell) provide, but not Python.

The easiest way to do get the same effect is to be explicit:

```
bits = line.split(' ')
src, tmp, dst = bits[0], bits[1], bits[2:]
```

If you really want to, you can indirectly use pattern matching by passing the arguments to a function:

```
def doStuff(src, tmp, *dst):
  # do stuff

doStuff(*line.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (1):
    line = file1.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    tokens = line.split();
    for (count, token) in enumerate(tokens,start=1):
        print str(tokens[0]) + " " + str(token)
```